# Extracting Return Statement Variable Names outside function definition

Tags: python

I am trying to get the structure information of python functions and classes. Let's consider the following function as an example:

```
def sample_function(parameter_1, parameter_2):
    # some logic
    return return_value
```

Using python's "inspect" library, I am able to get the function description (if available) and input parameter names, but I am unable to get the names of the variables being returned.

Since I want to get the input and output format templates, I need to figure out a way to get the names of the variables being returned. (P.S that a function /class might even return more than 1 variable and the return statement need not be the last line in the function/class and in some rare cases, there might be conditional return statements where the variables being returned might differ from one condition to another)

Comment: Can you explain why you need the _name_ of the variable being returned?

Comment: "I am unable to get the names of the variables being returned." That's because you **aren't** returning a variable. You can't actually do that. You return a *value*, which is computed from an *expression*. You could equally well write `return 3 * 4`, or `return 'hi mom'`.

Comment: You can use the `ast` module to parse the source code, then loop for the `return` statement in that.

Comment: Maybe you'd rather `return {'return_value': return_value}`, i.e. explicitly give the results a name in the function. Alternatives are tuples and in particular the `namedtuple` function.